# Problem with calendar script

Tags: javascript

Calendar displays some weird dates. Rhe month date is supposed to start at friday but starts on tuesday: http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/2927/cal.jpg.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
            monthnames = new Array("January","Februrary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"); 
            var linkcount=0; 
            function addlink(month, day, href) 

                { 
                var entry = new Array(3); 
                entry[0] = month; 
                entry[1] = day; 
                entry[2] = href; 
                this[linkcount++] = entry; 
                } 
                Array.prototype.addlink = addlink; 
                linkdays = new Array(); 
                monthdays = new Array(12);
                monthdays[0]=31; 
                monthdays[1]=28; 
                monthdays[2]=31; 
                monthdays[3]=30; 
                monthdays[4]=31; 
                monthdays[5]=30; 
                monthdays[6]=31; 
                monthdays[7]=31; 
                monthdays[8]=30;
                monthdays[9]=31; 
                monthdays[10]=30;
                monthdays[11]=31;
                todayDate=new Date(); 
                thisday=todayDate.getDay(); 
                thismonth=todayDate.getMonth(); 
                thisdate=todayDate.getDate(); 
                thisyear=todayDate.getYear(); 
                thisyear = thisyear % 100; 
        thisyear = ((thisyear < 50) ? (2000 + thisyear) : (1900 + thisyear)); 
    if (((thisyear % 4 == 0) && !(thisyear % 100 == 0)) || (thisyear % 400 == 0)) 
                { 
                monthdays[0]++; 
                } 
                startspaces=thisdate; 
                while (startspaces > 7) 
                { 
                startspaces-=7; 
                startspaces = thisday - startspaces + 1; 
                } 
                while (startspaces < 0) {
                startspaces += 7;


                } 

                document.write("<table border=1 bgcolor=white "); 
                document.write("bordercolor=black><font color=black>"); 
                document.write("<tr><td colspan=7><center><strong>" + monthnames[thismonth] + " " + thisyear + "</strong></center></font></td></tr>");                                  document.write("<tr>"); 
                document.write("<td align=center>Su</td>"); 
                document.write("<td align=center>M</td>"); 
                document.write("<td align=center>Tu</td>"); 
                document.write("<td align=center>W</td>"); 
                document.write("<td align=center>Th</td>"); 
                document.write("<td align=center>F</td>"); 
                document.write("<td align=center>Sa</td>"); 
                document.write("</tr>"); 
                document.write("<tr>"); 
                for (s=0;s<startspaces;s++) 
                {
                document.write("<td> </td>"); 
                }
                count=1; 
                while (count <= monthdays[thismonth]) 
                { 
                for (b = startspaces;b<7;b++) 

                { 
                linktrue=false; 
                document.write("<td>"); 
                for (c=0;c<linkdays.length;c++) 

                { 
                if (linkdays[c] != null) 

                { 
                if ((linkdays[c][0]==thismonth + 1) && (linkdays[c][2]==count)) 
                { 
                document.write("<a href=\"" + linkdays[c][2] + "\">"); linktrue=true; 
                } 
                } 
                } 
                if (count==thisdate) 
                { 
                document.write("<font color='FF0000'><strong>");
                } 
                if (count <= monthdays[thismonth]) 
                { document.write(count);
                } 
                else { document.write(" ");
                } 
                if (count==thisdate) 
                { document.write("</strong></font>"); 
                } 
                if (linktrue) { document.write("</a>"); 
                }
                document.write("</td>"); count++; 
                } 
                document.write("</tr>"); 
                document.write("<tr>"); 
                startspaces=0; 
                } 
                document.write("</table></p>"); 
</SCRIPT>
```

I can't seem to follow the code because I'm just new with javascript and programming, got this code from here: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2608&lngWId=2

Answer (score 2):

The calculations in this code are just plain **wrong**. I suggest you don't bother fixing it. Instead, use a reliable calendar that is widely used like the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)